# how to remove a child composite from parent composite in swt?

Tags: java, swt

I want to remove a child from its parent without. I tried to invisible it, exclude it, destroy it. Nothing helped. Or could it possible to add new set of children to parent ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to relayout the UI after disposing a control :

```
 if(! child.isDisposed()){
    child.dispose();
 }
 paramComposite.layout(true, true);
```

If you use a GridLayout in paramComposite you can exclude the cell :

```
 if(child.getLayoutData() instanceof GridData){
    ((GridData)child.getLayoutData() ).exclude = true;
 }
 paramComposite.layout(true, true);
```

To add a new child :

```
 Composite newChild = new Composite(paramComposite , SWT.NON) 
 paramComposite.layout(true, true);
```

Or change the parent of an existing control :

```
 existingControl.setParent(paramComposite );
 existingControl.setLayoutData(existingControlLayoutData);
 paramComposite.layout(true, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call `child.dispose()` in order to remove any control (including composites) from its parent. After disposing of a control, it cannot be used any more. I.e. all methods except `isDisposed()` will throw an `SWTException`.

Comment: I could dispose it only after it has drawn, right? But I want like that composite should not come into the UI itself. Can I call dispose on any event which should be called after loading? Is any event available like that?

Comment: @GabrialDavid You can dispose of a control at any time, you don't have to wait for it to be drawn or anything else. Perhaps you should show us an example of the code you are having problems with.

Comment: ` @Override
    protected void createContent( Composite paramComposite )
    {
        super.createContent( paramComposite );
       
            final Control[] hj = paramComposite.getChildren();
            hj[2].dispose();
                  }`

Comment: @GabrialDavid Edit your question to show us code (click the `edit` link below the question). Explain what your code is trying to do. Prefereably show us a [mcve]

Comment: @GabrialDavid Why do you want to dispose of a composite before it is shown? Why create it in the first place?

Comment: Actually that `super.createContent(paramComposite)` is must. it should happen because that's where i get what composites i want. And the situation is i can't duplicate the code that is available in super call. But i just want to ged rid of last child of paramComposite. so i did diposing of it. it throws below exception. what may i do ? dispose call should not be made in this place, right?
`org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)`

Comment: @GabrialDavid Again, we can't help you unless you provide a [mcve] - please read the link.

Comment: I have got that done. Now I could make that composite invisible. when I tried to dispose it, I threw exception. But what I did is I iterated all children and I disposed it first, then I set width height to zero and grabExcessHorizontalSpace grabExcessVerticalSpace to false. Now that composite is probably not in Earth ;-))